# How to control particles directly while preventing the particle system from doing the same?

Tags: unity-game-engine, particle-system

I have lots of same simple objects that are affecting gameplay, <s>thousands of them!</s> Well, not thousands, but really many. So if I make them GameObjects, the FPS decreases, especially when spawning them. Even with pooling. I should try a different approach.

You know that particle system in Unity3D can render many particles very fast. It also automatically controls particles, emits and removes them. But in my case, positions and lifetimes of objects are managed by game logic, and particle system is not allowed to do anything without my command, even reorder particles.

I am trying to use `SetParticles` method to control particles. It works in test project, where I use `GetParticles` first. I can even remove particles setting lifetime to -1, but can't spawn new ones. Also it does not prevent particle system from controlling particles.

I can disable emission so no particles will be created automatically.
I can set particles speed to 0 so they will not move.
I can set lifetime to huge number so they will not be removed.

I have an pool of `Particle` instances, to avoid unnessessary GC allocations. Objects receive a reference to particle when they are spawned, change it when updated, and set lifetime -1 and return it to pool when deleted. The pool stores this:

```
private ParticleSystem.Particle [] _unusedParticles;
private int                        _unusedCount;
private ParticleSystem.Particle [] _array;
```

`_unused` array and counter are needed for pooling, and `_array` stores all particles, used and unused alike, and is used in `SetParticles` call.

The main disadvantage of this method is that it doesn't work, probably because `SetParticles` does not create new particles. Also I guess it doesn't do anything with particles draw order, that's why it's poorly suited for bullet hell games where bullet patterns should look nice.

**What should I do to properly disable automatic control of particles and properly setup direct control, with spawning and removing?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for might be

```
    List<Matrix4x4> matrixes=new List<Matrix4x4>();
    for (...)
    {
        matrixes.Add(Matrix4x4.TRS( position,rotation,scale));
    }
    Graphics.DrawMeshInstanced(mesh,0,material, matrixes);
```

On each frame you can just update positions, rotations and scales, and get all the instances rendered on the GPU in one drawcall (pretty darn fast compared to seperate gameobjects). You can render up to 1000 instances in one call using this way

Comment: Interesting. But docs say that it uses GPU instancing. Does WebGL support it?

Comment: I am not entirely sure. I think it might do, there's a more advanced version called DrawMeshInstancedIndirect which requires compute buffer support, but I think normal,direct instancing should work (it does work on android)

Comment: Ok, I will try this. Thank you @zambari

Comment: Unfortunately, DrawMeshInstancedIndirect is incompatible with WebGL, throws an InvalidOperationException: Instancing is not supported . However, it works on desktop platform.

Comment: I accept this answer because it's useful for those who target desktop and there is no constraint about webgl in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Create an *empty* `GameObject`, then add the `ParticleSystem` as child. **Set `playOnAwake` to true.**

Now when you need it, set `GameObject.SetActive` to `true` else `false`.

To get each of them use `ParticleSystem.GetParticles`, modify them and `ParticleSystem.GetParticles`.

I hope this is [what](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.GetParticles.html) you are looking for.

```
ParticleSystem m_System;
ParticleSystem.Particle[] m_Particles;
public float m_Drift = 0.01f;

private void LateUpdate()
{
    InitializeIfNeeded();

    // GetParticles is allocation free because we reuse the m_Particles buffer between updates
    int numParticlesAlive = m_System.GetParticles(m_Particles);

    // Change only the particles that are alive
    for (int i = 0; i < numParticlesAlive; i++)
    {
        m_Particles[i].velocity += Vector3.up * m_Drift;
    }

    // Apply the particle changes to the Particle System
    m_System.SetParticles(m_Particles, numParticlesAlive);
}

void InitializeIfNeeded()
{
    if (m_System == null)
        m_System = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();

    if (m_Particles == null || m_Particles.Length < m_System.main.maxParticles)
        m_Particles = new ParticleSystem.Particle[m_System.main.maxParticles];
}
```

Comment: Switching particle system on and off is trivial, and I don't need that. I need total direct control on every particle position and size.

Comment: This still does not control particle spawning. It only modifies those which already exist. I seek a solution or hint how to control spawning, preferably preserving draw order of particles.

Answer (score 0):

After we created a particle system in editor, we should disable emission and shape, so only core part and renderer stay active.

The most important part is that **Simulation Speed** must be zero. A particle system will no longer emit, remove or process particles automatically. Only your code now manages them.

I use this class to control particles. Instead of binding a particle to an object, it has API for registering objects, smoke in this case. Also, it stores a temporary array for particles to avoid GC allocations, and particle count, to avoid using `particleCount` property of the particle system.

In `Update`, which is called by my game logic, the following happens:

- All objects that were despawned by game logic, are removed from list.
- If object count is greater than array length, the array is resized.
- If object count is greater than live particle count, `_particleSystem.Emit` call is made. If we call `SetParticles` without that, no new particles will appear. We must emit them first.
- `GetParticles` is called. Simple, but probably not the most efficient solution, but it preserves particles data. It may be optimized by setting **all** particle data on array creation and resizing. If you do so, remove `GetParticles` call and uncomment the line above. Also, your game logic should manage particles even more carefully.
- For each object, we let that object change a particle.
- Each particle without object should be removed, so their lifetime is set to negative number.
- `SetParticles` updates particles in system.

```cs
    public class SmokeSystem {

        private ParticleSystem             _particleSystem;
        private List <Smoke>               _smoke     = new List <Smoke> ();
        private ParticleSystem.Particle [] _particles = new ParticleSystem.Particle[256];
        private int                        _particleCount;


        public SmokeSystem (ParticleSystem particleSystem) {
            _particleSystem = particleSystem;
        }


        public void AddSmoke (Smoke smoke) => _smoke.Add (smoke);


        public void Update () {
            _smoke.RemoveAll (e => e.Despawned);

            if (_smoke.Count > _particles.Length) {
                int newSize = Max (_smoke.Count, 2 * _particles.Length);
                Array.Resize (ref _particles, newSize);
            }

            int count = _smoke.Count;
            if (count > _particleCount) {
                _particleSystem.Emit (count - _particleCount);
                // _particleCount = count;
            }
            _particleCount = _particleSystem.GetParticles (_particles);
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                _smoke [i].UpdateParticle (ref _particles [i]);
            }
            for (int i = count; i < _particleCount; i++) {
                _particles [i].remainingLifetime = -1;
            }
            _particleSystem.SetParticles (_particles, _particleCount);
            _particleCount = count;
        }

    }
```

It does not depend on GPU instancing support so it will work on WebGL.